# PDO No records getting shown PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to php and PDO and have been working on a `learn` as you go project but in past few days ran into problems.

What ever i try nothing seems to work.

here is my query to my database

```
$recieve = "$_SESSION[MemId]";
$sender = "$_SESSION[MemId]";
// select all data
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE recieve = :recieve 
NOT archive_recieve = 0";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindParam(':recieve', $recieve);
$stmt->execute();
```

I know the problem is with the query as the following works

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages 
    WHERE recieve = :recieve"
```

what i have i over looked?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: this is the part of code that isnt working i have stripped it from a page that has error handling :)

Comment: What is `NOT archive_recieve = 0";` in your query?

Comment: NOT archive_recieve = 0 is (I guess) making the error as your say the query without that line works right ?

Comment: you probably meant to do `WHERE recieve = :recieve 
AND archive_recieve != 0";` and make sure you started the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT` in SQL, by itself, is just an unary operator. You can not put it by itself without an actual clause.

In your case, you are trying to conjunct two separate clauses:

1. `recieve = :recieve`
2. `NOT archive_recieve = 0` (alternatively written as `archive_recieve <> 0` or `archive_recieve != 0`)

so, you'd need one of `AND`/`OR` etc.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages 
WHERE recieve = :recieve
    AND NOT archive_recieve = 0
```

**PS**: It is considered bad practice to use `SELECT *` in your queries. A developer should always be aware about what data is to be displayed at the end.

Comment: thanks for your answer yes i am only using SELECT * as i need all the info from the table anyway  :)